# Do AOE attacks deal Sneak Attack damage to all targets?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, sneak-attack

There are attacks that target an area (bursts, blasts, etc.); if I use an AOE attack and hit multiple enemies that I have combat advantage against, do I deal sneak attack damage to all of them?

Answer (score 10):

**No.**

From the Compendium (*emphasis mine*):

> **SNEAK ATTACK**
>
> When you make an attack with a light blade, a hand crossbow, a shortbow, or a sling and hit *an* enemy granting combat advantage to you, that enemy takes extra damage based on your level (see the Sneak Attack table). You can deal this extra damage only *once per turn*.

Sneak attack can only be applied once per turn, and is applied when you hit the target. Once you hit one of the targets and apply sneak attack to it, you no longer have sneak attack available to apply to other targets that round.

Comment: There is an epic tier feat that lets you choose an encounter power and apply sneak attack to all enemies hit with it (that you have CA on). "Whirlwhind Sneak Attack". But that's probably out of scope at this point.